# Stretching height DIV under another DIV with fixed height

Tags: html, css, height, stretch

I've made the picture to talk less. Hope you will understand.
The problem is that stretching 100% height DIV under other DIV with fixed height doesn't stretch properly.

[image: Problem is]

Here's example to work with: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5h2byu2b/3/)

css:

```
.controlling-div {
    width: 200px; 
    height: 200px;
}

.stretching-container-div {
    width: 100%; 
    height: 100%;
}

.fixed-height-div {
    height: 40px;
    background-color: #ff8811;
    border-radius: 20px;
}

.stretching-height-div {
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #ff2266;
    border-radius: 20px;
}
```

html:

```
<div class="controlling-div"><!-- width & height can be changed -->
    <div class="stretching-container-div"><!-- 100%-container -->
        <div class="fixed-height-div"></div><!-- fixed height -->
        <div class="stretching-height-div"></div><!-- height 100% - fixed height -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this style for `stretching-height-div`. Here the Height refers 100% minus 40px(fixed-height-div's height)

It works fine for me. Here is a **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/nrsantharam/5h2byu2b/9/)**

```
.stretching-height-div {
    height: -moz-calc(100% - 40px); /* Firefox */
    height: -webkit-calc(100% - 40px); /* Chrome, Safari */
    height: calc(100% - 40px); /* IE9+ and future browsers */
    background-color: #ff2266;
    border-radius: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5h2byu2b/10/)

```
.stretching-height-div {
    height: calc(100% - 40px);
    background-color: #ff2266;
    border-radius: 20px;
}
```